# Typescript dynamically create interface

Tags: javascript, typescript

I use simple-schema to define DB schemas in an object:

```
{
   name: 'string',
   age: 'integer',
   ...
}
```

Is it somehow possible to create an interface or class from this object, so I don't have to type everything twice?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can do this, but it might be more trouble than it's worth unless you think you might be changing the schema.  TypeScript doesn't have built-in ways of inferring types in a way that you want, so you have to coax and cajole it to do so:

---

First, define a way of mapping the literal names `'string'` and `'integer'` to the TypeScript types they represent (presumably `string` and `number` respectively):

```
type MapSchemaTypes = {
  string: string;
  integer: number;
  // others?
}

type MapSchema<T extends Record<string, keyof MapSchemaTypes>> = {
  -readonly [K in keyof T]: MapSchemaTypes[T[K]]
}
```

Now if you can take an appropriately typed schema object like the one you specified, and get the associated type from it:

```
const personSchema = {name: 'string', age: 'integer'}; 
type Person = MapSchema<typeof personSchema>; // ERROR
```

Oops, the problem is that `personSchema` is being inferred as `{name: string; age: string}` instead of the desired `{name: 'string'; age: 'integer'}`.  You can fix that with a type annotation:

```
const personSchema: { name: 'string', age: 'integer' } = { name: 'string', age: 'integer' }; 
type Person = MapSchema<typeof personSchema>; // {name: string; age: number};
```

But now it feels like you're repeating yourself.  Luckily there is a way to force it to infer the proper type:

```
function asSchema<T extends Record<string, keyof MapSchemaTypes>>(t: T): T {
  return t;
}
const personSchema = asSchema({ name: 'string', age: 'integer' }); // right type now
type Person = MapSchema<typeof personSchema>; // {name: string; age: number};
```

UPDATE 2020-06: in more recent TS versions you can use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to get the same result:

```
const personSchema = { name: 'string', age: 'integer' } as const;
type Person = MapSchema<typeof personSchema>;
```

That works!

---

See it in action [on the Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PQgEGcFMBcFcAcCwAoaBPelQFkCG8BlAYwAtIBbXAFQ0nFAF5QBvFUCaAJwEsA7AcwBcHHgIDcbUH2iR+kTsN6xyAI3kTk7MLl5pQAe2hlO4ADSgANtwDWWI3UgB+SSv36LkHcNfvPvDewAZhb6uNCKymqcAaBKqvIR8dGSnLKQAB7wwgBKsgCimTFg5PqpjqAoAL4o6Jg4+MRklAA8VKAZMrwAJvS5RKVdzeBcfPzmtmj6gfWEpBTUtOAAfEuMLJIAtKm4Xfq8FnoA2gDSUrygE1OgVAC6wnizTQuY4IdUJzc3VSiBsLxE0G4e1AuHAjXmrXa6U6PVAfQGQxGAnGkEm0we4MoNBeKwAFOFrgBKYRtViaUCpOCcc7QDTVZAoEDAUCwKBSaAofq8YagTAmPaY3BrZixXDkSDCADkw1E-El5lwcil0jSnEloEqIPoXOGGlqWAACvJwMCmBi5i19Vc+SbeIKlhoddBeca9sIjfzzkwyexeGKJaBJQAxVJdeWSRUBgDMAFYqhpOXsefALLgiJBBWtQYLcSK-eKpTLRvLLGFuHAugHJcFQtASyEBOXYJWpTWwiXeNx0wbU+mqPoAGrccDlqU+Dw6dWVQl62igHtprBmhoW3DNK3TFOL+2OpPOrfp929pfrcn5qsG3A8cDh8mpwEVgMAFgAHAA6F8xgBsX9Mkgb-BNi2oAAExvrGIEgX+Z5dpAC59oOw6jqAXCwJA8ZAA).  Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Is there a way to make it work like this?
`const personObj = { name: 'string', age: 'integer' }
type Person = MapSchema<typeof asSchema(personObj)>; `
I have been very unsuccessful at encapsulating this.

Comment: Can this answer be improved using the new Typescript 4.1?
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1/
I am unsure, still unfamiliar with advanced TS features.

Comment: @nstrelow I don't see how; the current version is pretty minimal. If we were remapping keys as well as values then the new `as`-clauses-in-mapped-types would help but we're not.

Comment: That is cool. Now, if it was recursive on a deep opbject... =)

Comment: This works because the keys are all different types, but if you have string, string, from what I've tested, it doesnt work

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can declare dynamic interfaces. However, you can create a [type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases) for objects with known properties.

You can create an object that maps string literals to actual types, e.g. `'integer' => number`, but that is not relevant to the question. I don't know what framework you're using but the following example works for a similar looking framework: Mongoose.

users.js

```
export const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    value: Number
});

export const Users = mongoose.Model('users', UserSchema);

export type User = { [K in keyof typeof UserSchema]: any } ;
```

usage:

```
import { User, Users } from './user';

Users.find({}).exec((err: Error, res: User) => { ... })
```

The returned result should have the same keys as `UserSchema`, but all values are mapped to any as you would still have to map string literals to types.

Comment: Is it possible to assert that a type (`User`) contains _every_ key of the javascript object (`UserSchema`)?

Comment: I wanted to do some something similar to @jcalz `MapSchema` util, but I'm not working with any sort of real database schema, I just have a simple object of field names and their default values. I didn't like using the `{ [K in keyof Thing]: string }` syntax cause I wanted to assert that _every_ key of my "schema" is enforced for the created type - I was able to answer my own question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64778252/create-typescript-interface-based-on-a-const-defaultvalues-map/64778253#64778253