# typescript dynamically create interface with nested structure

Tags: typescript, dynamic, types, type-inference

There is a great answer by @jcalz on how to dynamically create interface: [Typescript dynamically create interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45771307/typescript-dynamically-create-interface)

However I was wondering whether we could do the same with nested structure and integrate an optional parameter, see the `?` below.

Example from

```
{"names": {"firstName": "string", "lastName": "?string"} , "age": "number" }
```

output

```
{name: {firstName: string, lastName?: string}, age: number}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on his answer you can define own types. So you can define there '?string' too. But I guess it will require to specify the property anyway with value of `string` or `undefined`.

```js
type MapSchemaTypes = {
  string: string;
  integer: number;
  '?string': string | undefined;
}
```

I was managed to do it like that:

```js
const pattern = {
  "names": {
    "firstName": "string", 
    "lastName": "?string"
  },
  "age": "number",
  "name": "string",
  "lastName": "?string",

} as const;

type FILTER_PROPS<Base, Condition> = {
    [Key in keyof Base]: Base[Key] extends Condition ? Key : never;
}[keyof Base];

type Pattern<T> = {
  [K in FILTER_PROPS<T, '?string' | '?number'>]?:
    T[K] extends '?number' ? number
    : T[K] extends '?string' ? string
    : never
} & {
  [K in FILTER_PROPS<T, 'string' | 'number' | {[SK in keyof any]: any}>]:
    T[K] extends 'number' ? number 
    : T[K] extends 'string' ? string 
    : T[K] extends {} ? Pattern<T[K]>
    : never
};

const a: Pattern<typeof pattern> = {
  names: {
    firstName: 'Test',
  },
  name: 'required',
  age: 123,
};
```