# Create typescript interface based on a const defaultValues map

Tags: javascript, typescript

I wanted to do some something similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45777530/565877

But I'm not working with any sort of real database schema, I just have a simple object of field names and their default values, like so:

```
export const FormFieldDefaults = {
  firstName: '',
  lastName: '',
  dateOfBirth: ''
}
```

I want to generate this respective type:

```
export type FormFields = {
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
  dateOfBirth: string
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out all we need is the [`typeof` type operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html):

```
export const FormFieldDefaults = {
  firstName: '',
  lastName: '',
  dateOfBirth: ''
}

export type FormFields = typeof FormFieldDefaults
```