# Typescript interface - add new value dynamically or create the interface dynamically

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, interface, angular-material

I have an Angular Material Table. Obviously, I have an interface from which is created the dataSource for the table. Is there any possibility to add a new value dynamically in the interface, or at least to create the interface dynamically? Because the data which is coming from the backend it's unknown.

Example: from this:

```
export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}
```

to this:

```
export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
  index: number;
}
```

or from this:

```
export interface PeriodicElement {}
```

to this:

```
export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
  index: number;
}
```

Comment: hhhmmm If it's almost same interface but with different number of fields present, you might use DataSource<Partial<PeriodicElement>>(elements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It will be better to use it like,

```js
export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
  [key: string]: string | number;
}
```

or just

```js
export interface PeriodicElement {
  [key: string]: string | number;
}
```

2. Otherwise you can create separate models and use [union(`|`)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html) operator.
3. Also you can use [Partials](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) to achieve this.
4. For creating dynamically [Refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45771307/typescript-dynamically-create-interface)