# Typescript interface for dynamic object

Tags: typescript

Suppose I can have objects like this:

```
const filters = {
    name: { value: 'some-value', rank: 'some-value' },
    place: { value: 'some-value', population: 'some-value' },
}
```

and it could also be like this...

```
const filters = {
    name: { value: 'some-value', rank: 'some-value' },
    place: { value: 'some-value', population: 'some-value' },
    description: { value: 'some-value', translation: 'some-value' },
    popularity: { value: 'some-value', ranking: 'some-value' },
}
```

How do I create an interface for that *(a dynamic object)*?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45777530/5779165) answer your question ?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to make `description` and `popularity` optional by adding a `?`, like so:

### Approach 1

```
interface Filters {
    name: object,
    place: object,
    description?: object,
    popularity?: object,
}
```

For more information on property modifiers, see the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html)

Another approach would be to use interface inheritance by using the keyword `extends`

### Approach 2

```
interface ParentFilters {
    name: object,
    place: object
}
```

And for the derived interface

```
interface derivedFilters extends parentFilter {
   description: object,
   popularity: object,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to create a type which forces to be `{ a }` or `{ a, b, c }`. This is called **Discriminated Unions** and you can read more about this problem [here](https://css-tricks.com/typescript-discriminated-unions/).

You can use booth approaches which @SimonRosengren mentioned. To force typesafety when defining an object you have to implicitly say which type is what:

```
interface FilterTypeBase {
    name: { value: string, rank: string },
    place: { value: string, population: string }
}

interface FilterTypeExtended extends FilterTypeBase {
    description: { value: string, translation: string },
    popularity: { value: string, ranking: string }
}

//  OK
const filters: FilterTypeBase = {
    name: { value: 'some-value', rank: 'some-value' },
    place: { value: 'some-value', population: 'some-value' },
}

// ❌ ERROR: Property 'popularity' is missing
const filters2: FilterTypeExtended = {
    name: { value: 'some-value', rank: 'some-value' },
    place: { value: 'some-value', population: 'some-value' },
    description:  { value: "string", translation: "string" }
}
```

If you use want to decide in a function which of booth variantes your type is. You can do this with narrowing:

```
type FilterType = FilterTypeBase | FilterTypeExtended 

function doSomething(filter: FilterType) {
    if('description' in filter) {
        // Here it's the extended type
    }
}
```

Typescript docs: [Narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html)